# Querying Azure Mobile App TableController

Tags: entity-framework, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile Apps and TableControllers in my project. Development has been going quite smoothly, until now. One of my tables relies on quite a bit of business logic in order to return the appropriate entities back to the client. To perform this business logic I need to get some parameters from the client (specifically, a date range).

I know I could use an APIController to return the data, but won't that break the entity syncing that's provided by the SyncTables in Xamarin?

My current logic in my GetAll is:

```
public IQueryable<WorkItemDTO> GetAllWorkItem()
    {
        //Return all the work items that the user owns or has been assigned as a resource.
        var query = MappedDomainManager.QueryEntity().Where(x => x.OwnerId == UserProfileId || x.Resources.Where(r => r.AssignedResourceId == UserProfileId).Count() > 0);

        return query.Project().To<WorkItemDTO>();
    }
```

What I would like is to be able to somehow pass through a start and end date that I can then use to build up my list of WorkItemDTO objects. The main problem is that a WorkItem entity can actually spawn off multiple WorkItemDTO objects as a WorkItem can be set to be recurring. So for example say a WorkItem is recurring once a week, and the user wants to see a calendar for 1 month, that single WorkItem will spawn 4 separate concrete WorkItemDTO objects.

Then when a user modifies one of those WorkItemDTO objects on the client side, I want it to be sent back as a patch that creates its own WorkItem entity.

Does anyone know how I can get a TableController to receive parameters? Or how to get an APIController to work so that client syncing isn't affected?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Jacob

Comment: Do you need the query parameter on your Get endpoint or on the Post/Patch/Delete endpoints as well?

Comment: @lindydonna-msft I just need the parameter on the Get endpoint. The Post/Patch and Delete will work the normal way. It's just the retrieval of the initial list of DTOs that's problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server, you can add a query parameter to the table controller get method easily, by adding a parameter with the right name and type.

For instance, you could add a `dateFilter` query parameter as follows:

```
public IQueryable<WorkItemDTO> GetAllWorkItem(string dateFilter)
```

This would be called by passing a dateFilter=value query parameter. You can use any data type that ASP.NET Web API supports in serialization. (Note that if you don't have a GetAll that takes no query parameters, you will get an Http 405 Method Not allowed if you do a Get without this query parameter.)

On the client, as noted by @JacobJoz, you just use the method [IMobileServiceTableQuery.WithParameters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/master/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/Table/Query/Linq/IMobileServiceTableQuery.cs#L197) to construct the query that is passed to `PullAsync`. If you have multiple incremental sync queries against the same table and they use different values for the parameters, you should make sure to include those in the queryId to pull.

That is, if you have one query with parameters foo=bar and another that is foo=baz for the same sync table, make sure you use two different query IDs, one that includes "bar" and one that includes "baz". Otherwise, the 2 incremental syncs can interfere with one another, as the queryId is used as a key to save the last updated timestamp for that sync table. See [How offline synchronization works](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync/#how-sync-works).

<s>The part that is unfortunately hard is passing the query parameter as part of the  offline sync pull. Offline sync only works with table controllers, FYI.</s>

There is an overloaded extension method for `PullAsync` that takes a dictionary of parameters, but unfortunately it requires a string query rather than `IMobileServiceTableQuery`:

```
PullAsync(this IMobileServiceSyncTable table, string queryId, string query, IDictionary<string, string> parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

(I've filed a bug to fix this: [Add a generic PullAsync overload that accepts query parameters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/181)).

The problem is that there's no easy way to convert from `IMobileServiceTableQuery` to an OData query string, since you'd need to access internal SDK methods. (I filed another issue: [Add extension method ToODataString for IMobileServiceTableQuery](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/182).)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this issue and filing the necessary requests to get this resolved. I already implement a delegating handler to handle re-authentication when required. In this case though, I think (1) is probably the path of least resistance for me, at least for this particular use case. All I need to pass through is the date range, so there won't ever be a need to pass through extra query parameters through the CreateQuery().Where(.....). This means that I should be able to create my ODataString and pass it through. What could possibly go wrong :)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Feel free to post new questions if you have issues. If my answer was helpful, please mark to accept it. :)

Comment: I've finally got back onto the project. I was reading through the MobileServiceTableQuery<T> sourcecode on github, and I came across a method called WithParameters that seems to do what I want. Can you take a look at the post below and see if it's a reasonable approach?

Answer (score 1):

I've looked through the source code for MobileServiceTableQuery on github. It looks like it exposes a method called WithParameters. I have chained that method call onto CreateQuery in order to generate the query to the server, and it seems to do what I want.

Here is the client code:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters.Add("v1", "hello");

var query = WorkItemTable.CreateQuery().WithParameters(parameters);
await WorkItemTable.PullAsync("RetrieveWorkItems", query);
```

On the server I have a GetAll implementation that looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<WorkItem> GetAllWorkItem(string v1)
{
    //return IQueryable after processing business logic based on parameter
}
```

The parameterized version of the method gets called successfully. I'm just not entirely sure what the impacts are from an incremental pull perspective.

Comment: Yes, that works!  I did not realize that this method existed. I looked at the code and the tests (and tried it out), and it does exactly what you want. I revised my answer.